# Android ListView selected item highlight

Tags: android, list, layout, view, highlight

I have horizontal listView with TextView items, my item layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayHorizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp" >
</TextView>

<View 
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to highlight only one selected item by setting borded to it's textView, eg. when I click to item1 I want to see this item with small border, and now when I click item2 - this will be highlighted and border from item1 will disappear.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `ListView.getSelected()` which should return the list item view you want to highlight, find the `TextView` in it, change border and remember it to reset border when another item is selected

Answer (score 2):

In your activity create a private class like the following:

```
private class ListChoice 
{
    private int value;

    public ListChoice() 
    {
        value = -1;
    }

    public void setListChoice(int v) 
    { 
        value = v; 
    }

    public final int getListChoice()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

In setOnItemClickListener set the clicked row

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        listChoice.setListChoice(position);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

In the listview adapter use it to highlight or disable highlight

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ......
    if(position == listChoice.getListChoice())
    {
        //highlight clicked item
    }
    else
    {
        //disable highlight for the rest of items
    }
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- May be you need property to store last highlight item. 
  Etc:

  View lastHighlightItem=null;
- Overwrite [onItemClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html#onItemClick%28android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) method.
  Etc:

> onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id){
>
> ```
>        if(lastHighlightItem!=null)
>           lastHighlightItem.recover();
>         //recover unHighlight state 
>         view.highlight();//Highlight as you like
>         lastHighlightItem = view;
> ```

}